# ListView does not update after .onDelete is called and firestore document is updated

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a sheet that creates a list based on filtered documents from firestore (if userid is contained in an array in the document, the rest of the document's data is used to populate the list 'row')

I'm trying to implement a swipe to delete functionality, and for the most part it works, except after the userid is deleted from the firestore document array, the list is not updated in the UI - it disappears completely.

Here's the struct for the view containing the list mentioned above

```
struct OwnFlightSheet: View {
    @ObservedObject var flightViewModel = FlightsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(flightViewModel.ownFlights) { flight in
                    FlightRow(flight: flight)
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    // Get the index of the flight being deleted
                    if let index = indexSet.first {
                        let flight = flightViewModel.ownFlights[index]
                        // Call a method to remove the user's ID from the flight's ConList array
                        flightViewModel.removeUserFromFlight(flight: flight, userID: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")
                        flightViewModel.ownFlights.remove(at: index)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            flightViewModel.fetchListedFlights(userID: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I've implemented `fetchListedFlights` and `removeUserFromFlight`

```
func fetchListedFlights(userID: String) {
        db.collection(K.FStore.WalkCollection).addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.ownFlights = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> Flight? in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let docID = queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
                let flightNumber = data[K.FStore.FlightNumber] as? String ?? ""
                let depDate = data[K.FStore.DepartureDate] as? String ?? ""
                let cons = data[K.FStore.ConList] as? [String] ?? []
                let numCons = cons.count
                
                // Filter out flights that don't have the user's ID
                guard cons.contains(userID) else {
                    return nil
                }
                return Flight(id: docID, flightNumber: flightNumber, depDate: depDate, conList: cons, numCons: numCons)
            }
        }
    }

    
    func removeUserFromFlight(flight: Flight, userID: String) {
        // Assuming you have a reference to the Firestore document for the flight
        let docRef = db.collection(K.FStore.WalkCollection).document(flight.id)
        
        // Update the ConList array by removing the user's ID
        docRef.updateData([
            K.FStore.ConList: FieldValue.arrayRemove([userID])
        ]) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error removing user from flight: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("User removed from flight successfully!")
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried calling `fetchListedFlights` in the onDelete closure, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: In `OwnFlightSheet`, have you tried using `@StateObject` instead of `@ObservedObject`. Is `ownFlights` a "normal" array of structs?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Holy smokes! That was it! I'm blown away it was something so easy like that! I'm obviously new at swift (and making an app), do you think you could point me in a direction to learn more about why this worked? Also, if you submit it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app using `ObservableObject`: 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app). Note that in ios17 the whole of `ObservableObject` thing is/will be replaced by a new/better way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `OwnFlightSheet` use:

```
@StateObject var flightViewModel = FlightsViewModel()
```

Also have a look at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject